# Count of values across fields in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have the below test data.

```
A   B   C

M   O

M   M   M

M   M   M

N       O

P       N
```

I would like to get the total count of entries in this sample test data i.e 12

I have the below code to do the same, but i am getting an incorrect result.

Any help on how to rectify would be helpful.

```
test=  LOAD 'testdata' USING PigStorage(',') as (A:chararray,B:chararray,C:chararray); 
values = FOREACH test GENERATE A==''?'null':(A is null?'null':A)) as A,(B==''?'null':(B is null?'null':B)) as B,(C==''?'null':(C is null?'null':C)) as C;  
grp = GROUP values ALL;  
counting = FOREACH grp GENERATE group, COUNT(values.A)+COUNT(values.B)+COUNT(values.C);
```

This is giving answer as 15, rather than 12 .

I would also like to get the count of each of these values,like M=7, N=2, O=2, P=1.
I have written the below code.

```
test=  LOAD 'testdata' USING PigStorage(',') as (A:chararray,B:chararray,C:chararray); 
values = FOREACH test GENERATE A==''?'null':(A is null?'null':A)) as A,(B==''?'null':(B is null?'null':B)) as B,(C==''?'null':(C is null?'null':C)) as C;  
grp = GROUP values ALL;  
    A = FOREACH grp {
B =FILTER test.A=='M' OR test.B=='M' OR test.C=='M';
GENERATE group, COUNT(B);
};
```

I am getting an error "Scalar has more than one row in the output".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are counting the column names as well in your final count.Modify the script to ignore the first row and then group by and count.

```
test=  LOAD 'testdata' USING PigStorage(',') as (A:chararray,B:chararray,C:chararray); 

ranked = rank test;
test1 = Filter ranked by ($0 > 1); --Note:rank_test should work.

values = FOREACH test1 GENERATE A==''?'null':(A is null?'null':A)) as A,(B==''?'null':(B is null?'null':B)) as B,(C==''?'null':(C is null?'null':C)) as C;  
grp = GROUP values ALL;  
counting = FOREACH grp GENERATE group, COUNT(values.A)+COUNT(values.B)+COUNT(values.C);
```

Comment: What is rank_test here ?

Comment: The answer should basically ignore the empty fields to provide the count of fields present in the data set, which is 12 .

Comment: Rank assigns row numbers for the records in the relation.rank_test is a new column with row number.This is to eliminate the column headings so when we filter we use rank_test > 1 to remove the first row A,B,C.Try running the script and see what you get.It should give you 12.

Comment: It indicates a "Projected field [rank_test] does not exist in schema" .
Which I felt would be an obvious one. Please let me know what could be done for this.

Comment: Do you have the statement ranked = rank test; ? If you do then it will add a new column called rank_test to the relation ranked.Try using $0 instead of rank_test.

Comment: Yes.Putting the $0 worked for me.That was so helpful.

Comment: How to group values across columns to get M=6,N=2,O=2,P=1?